# Class could not be found error

Tags: genie

Doing my best to try to solve my problems w/o posting questions here. However, valadoc search system has been broken recently and #vala IRC channel is less helpful when it comes to Genie code (understandably).

### Aim

I am trying to provide a OOP Gtk interface from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526346/avoiding-global-variables-in-genie) question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905309/execl-error-debuging) early pandoc gui app.

### Problem

I got stuck with the error `` pandoc-gui.gs:56.24-56.43: error: The type name `DocumentFileSelector' could not be found\n     _document_selector:DocumentFileSelector `` at compilation.  The class is defined later in the program, but I can't seem to find what I did wrong that makes it not visible to init.

This is the init routine:

```
init
    Intl.setlocale()
    Gtk.init (ref args)

    var header = new Header ( "Pandoc GUI" )
    var body = new WorkingFile(  )
    var app = new AppWindow ( header,body )
    var load_new_content_command = new Load( body, document_selector )
    var document_selector = new DocumentFileSelector( app )
    var convert_command = new Convert (document_selector)

    header.add_item( new OpenButton( load_new_content_command ) )
    header.add_item( new ConvertButton ( convert_command ) )

    app.show_all ()
    Gtk.main ()
```

This is the Convert class:

```
class Convert:Object implements Command

    _document_selector:DocumentFileSelector

    construct ( document_selector:DocumentFileSelector )

        _document_selector = document_selector

    def execute()

        var a = new ToPDF()
        a.convert.begin( document_selector.whichFile(), "output_file.pdf" )
```

And the interfaces:

```
interface Command:Object
        def abstract execute()

interface DocumentSelector:Object
        def abstract select():bool
        def abstract get_document():string
```

And the DocumentFileSelector class:

```
class DocumentFileSelector:Object implements DocumentSelector

    _parent:Window
    _uri:string = ""
    _filename:string = ""

    construct( parent:Window )
        _parent = parent

    def select():bool
        var dialog = new FileChooserDialog( "Open file",
                                        _parent,
                                        FileChooserAction.OPEN,
                                        dgettext( "gtk30", "_OK"),
                                        ResponseType.ACCEPT,
                                        dgettext( "gtk30", "_Cancel" ),
                                        ResponseType.CANCEL)

        selected:bool = false
        var response = dialog.run()
        case response
            when ResponseType.ACCEPT
                    _filename = dialog.get_filename()
                    _uri = dialog.get_uri()
                    selected = true
        dialog.destroy()
        return selected

    def whichFile():string
        return _uri

    def get_document():string
        text : string
        len : size_t
        try
                FileUtils.get_contents (_filename, out text, out len)
        except ex : FileError
                print "%s\n", ex.message
        return text
```

### Question

Why is DocumentFileSelector not being seen by init in this case?

**Note**: I am still figuring out how to write a minimally reproducible question, however it is not as simple as it sounds when it comes to OOP with all the interdependent parts. For this reason, here is the entire [**code**](http://pastebin.com/DScRC0zx) in case what I provided wasn't enough to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have encountered a bug in the Genie parser. There are three places in your code where you are using two indentations to indicate a single new block of code. These are:

1. Your interface definitions
2. The `case when ...` block in the `select()` method of `DocumentFileSelector`
3. The `try...except` block in the `get_document()` method of `DocumentFileSelector`

For example, change

```
interface Command:Object
        def abstract execute()
```

to

```
interface Command:Object
    def abstract execute()
```

Once you have fixed those you will encounter a number of other type errors in your code, but you should be able to figure out how to fix those from the Genie error messages.

The Genie parser is reading the two indentations, but gets confused because it doesn't keep a record it is looking for two dedentations to mark the end of the block. Anyone wishing to fix that take a look at [Developing Genie](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Genie/Developing).